# Как оформляются на письме собственные мысли?

Tags: пунктуация

В качестве примера приведу все тот же отрывок из В. Крапивина, что я приводила в прошлом вопросе о предложениях в скобках: *"И вообще для ангелов сандалии подходят больше, почти библейская обувь, подумал я"*. Так вот, я обратила внимание на то, что собственные мысли автор не оформляет как прямую речь, а отделяет всего лишь запятой.
Поясните, пожалуйста, в каких ситуациях размышления автора нужно оформлять как прямую речь, а когда можно записывать так, как показано в этом примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нераспространенные слова автора могут быть оформлены в виде вводного предложения, при этом различные варианты различаются интонацией  (набольшая выделительная интонация при оформлении в виде прямой речи):

(1) "А вы, думал я, отчего вы так глубоко и грустно безмолвны?" (2)Для сравнения: «Однако, – думал я, – умеют же они притворяться».

Слова автора оформляются как вводные предложения в различных случаях (не только при собственных авторских размышлениях), например: "Мастерство полководца, считает Толстой, должно заключаться в понимании народного духа".

Answer (score 1):

*Подумал (-а) я* может быть вводным предложением, а не словами автора **при пересказе**, когда воспроизводятся события прошлого. При этом не сохраняется интонация прямой речи и слов автора. Когда же описываются непосредственно происходящие события, используется прямая речь.

Интересно, что, казалось бы, аналогичные предложения *подумал он / она* среди вводных не числятся.